# CORS grpc Gateway GoLang

Tags: go, grpc-go, grpc-gateway

I have a vue.js 3 frontend, and I am calling a Golang backend via `grpc-gateway`. I have been at this for a while but I see light at the end of the tunnel.

I am currently facing a CORS issue. However, I am reading conflicting information on how to handle it. Therefore, I want to post and hopefully it helps someone.

Here is the code on how I init my mux server for GRPC (gateway)

```
func RunHttpServer(server *http.Server, httpEndpoint, grpcEndpoint, swaggerPath string) (err error) {
    server.Addr = httpEndpoint

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    defer cancel()

    // Register gROC server endpoint
    mux := runtime.NewServeMux(
        runtime.WithErrorHandler(func(ctx context.Context,
            mux *runtime.ServeMux,
            marshaler runtime.Marshaler,
            w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request,
            err error,
        ) {
            s, ok := status.FromError(err)
            if ok {
                if s.Code() == codes.Unavailable {
                    err = status.Error(codes.Unavailable, ErrUnavailable)
                }
            }

            runtime.DefaultHTTPErrorHandler(ctx, mux, marshaler, w, r, err)

        }),
    )

    opts := []grpc.DialOption{
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()),
        grpc.WithChainUnaryInterceptor(),
    }

    if err = api.RegisterApiServiceHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx, mux, grpcEndpoint, opts); err != nil {
        return
    }

    swMux := http.NewServeMux()
    swMux.Handle("/", mux)
    serveSwagger(swMux, swaggerPath)

    server.Handler = swMux

    return server.ListenAndServe()

}
```

Here is where I believe I should add the cors config, but I am not sure this is how I set it up in the server.go file..

```
var httpServer http.Server

// Run Http Server with gRPC gateway
g.Go(func() error {
    fmt.Println("Starting Http sever (port {}) and gRPC gateway (port {})",
        strconv.Itoa(cfg.Server.HTTPPort),
        strconv.Itoa(cfg.Server.GRPCPort),
    )

    return rest.RunHttpServer(
        &httpServer,
        ":"+strconv.Itoa(cfg.Server.HTTPPort),
        ":"+strconv.Itoa(cfg.Server.GRPCPort),
        "/webapi",
    )
})
```

error in console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/v1/test' from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
```

I am not sure where to add something like

```
func enableCors(w *http.ResponseWriter) {
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
}
```

and I feel the golang GRPC gateway should have something built in but I cannot find anything?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

----- update 1 -----

I have tried

```
func enableCors(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9000")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS")
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

and

```
func enableCors(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS")
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

and

```
func enableCors(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS")
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

in conjuction with

```
func serveSwagger(mux *http.ServeMux, swaggerPath string) {
    fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir(swaggerPath))
    prefix := "/swagger-ui"
    mux.Handle(prefix, http.StripPrefix(prefix, fileServer))
}
```

and still have the same issue.. Very frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the latest error you've provided in a comment:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080/v1/test' from origin 'localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Your browser is sending a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) (`OPTIONS` HTTP method) to ascertain whether the desired cross origin request can be made.

And the server is responding with a non-2xx response.

I suspect this is because your `enableCors` functions are propagating the request to the grpc-gateway handler, which is unhappy with the `OPTIONS` HTTP method and returning an error status, probably:

```
< HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
< Content-Type: application/json
< Vary: Origin
< Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2022 11:17:52 GMT
< Content-Length: 55
< 
{"code":12,"message":"Method Not Allowed","details":[]}
```

So to avoid that, you'd want to *not* propagate the request further in the case of a preflight request being made, e.g.

```
func enableCors(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9000")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS")
        if r.Method == http.MethodOptions {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
            return
        }
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

**However**, the above is likely still not a reasonable implementation of CORS handling. You should look to use an existing package for this, e.g. [github.com/rs/cors](https://github.com/rs/cors), which will handle this in a reasonable fashion, and also deal with any potential gotchas, etc.

So importing `github.com/rs/cors` and then doing something like:

```
server.Handler = cors.AllowAll().Handler(swMux)
```

should get you started by allowing everything through. The library will allow you to tailor to specific origins, HTTP methods, etc, as required.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to enrich your `swMux` with additional handler logic.

```
func enableCors(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Then, call this in your `RunHttpServer` function:

```
swMux := http.NewServeMux()
swMux.Handle("/", mux)
serveSwagger(swMux, swaggerPath)

server.Handler = enableCors(swMux)
```

[Here](https://github.com/heppu/simple-cors/blob/master/cors.go) is another example with more options enabled.
[Here](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/master/examples/internal/gateway/main.go) is an official example from `grpc-gateway` repo on how they handle CORS.

Comment: I do not think this will work. For example ` Cannot use 'enableCors(swMux)' (type http.Handler) as the type *ServeMux`

Comment: my bad, I put it in the wrong place. Edited the code.

Comment: I still get the same error 

ccess to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/v1/test' from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: where is your server code, where do you set up the server?

Comment: try to call by the grpcurl, if it's working then try to not use localhost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging locally, you should add a proxy to the front end to proxy to the back end service. There should be a vue.config.js file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).